# Strategy for creating a long running, interruptible function in Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to create a server in Node that will run on my Raspberry Pi to handle changing GPIO pins. (I'm new to Node but excited to be learning new stuff)

These pins control sprinkler valve relays using OpenSprinkler hardware, and only one valve should be allowed to open at a time. The hardware does not allow you to query the valve status, so it needs to be handled in software.

When a network request comes in, something akin to "operate station 1 for 15 minutes", I need to be able to fulfill that command and wait the appropriate number of minutes before setting the pin back to off. **Each execution should be able to stop itself, I do not want to rely on an external command to turn off the water, lest a software glitch turn my yard into a pond.**

If a second command arrives while the first one is operating, I want the first operation to terminate itself, then allow the second command to run. This termination will stop the operation early, log how many minutes it ran for, etc.

I wrote this already in Python using threads and Queues, but I'm looking to see if it can be done more cleanly in Node.

I'm curious if I should be looking at threads, spawning child processes, or something else to achieve what I'm looking for? I need some sort of non-blocking, long-running execution that can listen for signals to be interrupted.

Here's a concept of my idea, but the operateSprinkler function blocks so it needs to be modified or re-written.

```
net = require('net');

function operateSprinkler(minutes, station) {

    console.log('Operating Station ' + station + ' for ' + minutes + ' minutes.');

    var ms = minutes * 60 * 1000;
    var endTime = (new Date().getTime()) + ms;

    // Manipulate gpio pin to turn on sprinkler (pseudo-code here)
    gpio.on()

    while(new Date().getTime() < futureTime) {
        // Hang out until time expires
        // Listen for a signal that interrupts this function
    }
    else {
        gpio.off() // pseudo-code
    }

    console.log('Finished operating station.');
}

net.createServer(function(socket) {

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        try {            
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            // Make sure "minutes" and "station" were passed
            if (json.hasOwnProperty('minutes') && json.hasOwnProperty('station')) {
                operateSprinkler(json['minutes'], json['station']);
            }
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log('Error. Invalid command.');            
        }
        socket.end();
    });

}).listen(5000);

console.log("Server running at port 5000\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you'll want to rework your code to handle events, whether from timers or from your sprinkler controller.

In the example you provided, make use of setTimeout, storing the returned timeoutId, sprinkler station and any other data you need access to so you can cancel it later.

Replacing your operateSprinkler logic would then look something like:

```
/*
 * current station is false if not running
 *
 * or {
 *     station:   stationid,
 *     duration:  time,
 *     start:     Date.now(),
 *     timeoutId: timeoutId
 * }
 */
var currentStation = false;

function operateSprinkler(minutes, station) {

    if(currentStation) {
        console.log('Cancelling station: ' + currentStation.station);

        gpio.off(); // Will need some way to look up by station...

        clearTimeout(currentStation.timeoutId);
    }

    var ms = minutes * 60 * 1000;
    var endTime = (new Date().getTime()) + ms;

    currentStation = {
        station: station,
        duration: ms,
        start: Date.now();
    };

    console.log('Operating Station ' + station + ' for ' + minutes + ' minutes.');

    // Manipulate gpio pin to turn on sprinkler (pseudo-code here)
    gpio.on()

    currentStation.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        gpio.off();
        currentStation = false;

        console.log('Stopping station ' + currentStation.stationid);
        console.log('Finished operating station.');
    }, ms);
}
```

Comment: Wow, so much more simple than I made it out to be. Thanks for taking the time to mark up my original code to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `setTimeout`.

```
var timer = setTimeout(stopSprinkler, 15_minutes_in_seconds);
```

You can store this timer into a variable, and if/when another command comes in, simply check whether this variable is set or not. If it's set, you can use `clearTimeout` to stop the timer and manually handle stopping the sprinkler.